# Array of JSON object to Controller

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jqgrid

I'm using JQGrid and I have constructed a class call person.

I manage to pass a **List** as json to the jsp and display it on JQGrid.

May I know how can I pass the same list back to the controller for processing as a **List**?

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a json string to the controller and then deserialize it to `list`.
Perhaps [this link](http://json2java.blogspot.in/) can help you.